# Does apache have a way to change the process name for a generic vhost?

Tags: apache-2.2

With `mod_wsgi` there is a parameter to `WSGIDaemonProcess` to set the `display-name`.  For instance I can have:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myApp processes=4 threads=1 maximum-requests=1000 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup myApp
```

When I look at each process's memory usage with `ps -C apache2 xo pid,ppid,rss,cmd,comm --sort -rss`, `mod_wsgi` does something to the process to change the name that shows up under `cmd` so I get `(wsgi:myApp)` and the apache args in lieu of the the path to the apache executable.

How can I do that for the other child processes of Apache? As an additional part to this question, possibly a prerequisite to the first, can I isolate my vhosts to specific child processes?

Comment: When you say workers, are you now talking about the Apache child worker processes as opposed to the mod_wsgi daemon processes? Note that the only reason mod_wsgi can do this is because it is setting up the creation of the daemon processes it uses. They are entirely separate to the Apache child worker processes. The Apache child worker process actually proxy requests to the mod_wsgi daemon processes when needed.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, I was referring to the remaining child processes.

Comment: For Apache child worker processes there is no way to split the role they serve. This is because all Apache child worker processes will wait on the HTTP server listener port (80) and there isn't a way for a specific process to know in advance for what virtual host a inbound connection may be for. The only way get separation would be to run multiple Apache instances with a front end Apache. That still doesn't help in as much as you can't override name of Apache child worker processes.